# Find $p(t)$ y $B$ of floquet theorem where $A(t)=f(t)A$, $A$ is a constant 2x2 matriz

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the equation $x'=A(t)x$ with $A(t)$ a smooth $T$-periodic $n×n$-matrix, $x∈R^n$, $f(t)$ a smooth scalar $T$-periodic function. Consider the case when $n=2$, $A(t)=f(t)A_0$, $A_0$ is a constant matrix. Determine $P(t)$ and $B$ in the Floquet theorem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the initial value problem
$$\tag{1}
\dot x= A_0 f(t) x,\quad x(0)=x_0
$$
is
$$
x(t) = e^{\displaystyle  A_0\int_0^t f(\tau)\,d\tau}x_0.
$$
Indeed,
$$
\frac{dx}{dt}= e^{\displaystyle  A_0\int_0^t f(\tau)\,d\tau} A_0 f(t) x_0=
A_0 f(t)\, e^{\displaystyle  A_0\int_0^t f(\tau)\,d\tau} x_0= A_0 f(t) x.
$$
Let $g(t)=f(t)-a$, where $a$ is the average value of $f$ over the period:
$$
a= \frac1{T} \int_0^T f(\tau)\,d\tau.
$$
We have
$$
\int_0^t f(\tau)\,d\tau= at+\int_0^t (f(\tau)-a)\,d\tau=at+\int_0^t g(\tau)\,d\tau
=at+G(t),
$$
where $G(t)=\int_0^t g(\tau)\,d\tau$ is periodic because
$$
G(t+T)-G(t)= \int_t^{t+T} g(t)\,d\tau= \int_0^{T} g(t)\,d\tau
$$
$$
=\int_0^{T} (f(\tau)-a)\,d\tau= \int_0^{T} f(\tau)\,d\tau-\int_0^{T} a\,d\tau= 
aT-aT=0.
$$
Finally,
$$
x(t)= e^{\displaystyle  A_0(at+G(t))}x_0=
\underbrace{e^{\displaystyle  A_0 G(t)}}_{P(t)} e^{\displaystyle  \overbrace{A_0 a}^{B}t}x_0.
$$